# How do I forward Publisher output to a downstream Subscriber through a custom operator?

Tags: swift, operators, reactive-programming, combine

I have a potential use for Combine, but I am having a lot of trouble with the implementation details. The goal is to provide an Publisher that will do the following:

1. Search for a cached value, and emit that value, or:
2. Refer the subscriber to an upstream publisher that will emit a value, storing it in the appropriate cache location

**I understand that this could be done using existing operators, but I would like to learn how to make a custom `Operator`/`Publisher`/`Subscription` pattern, if possible.**

I'd like the usage to be similar to the following bit of pseduocode:

```
URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
    .cache(with: { someSortOfCachingPolicy })
    .sink()
```

In order to implement this, I am guessing at what Apple does for things like `map` and `flatMap`.

I have created a `CachePublisher` to try to capture the Upstream `Publisher`:

```
struct CachePublisher<Upstream: Publisher>: Publisher {
    typealias Output = Upstream.Output
    typealias Failure = Upstream.Failure
    
    var upstream: Upstream
    
    var getCache: ()->Output?
    var setCache: (Output)->Void
    
    func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Input {
        let subscription = CachePublisherSubscription(subscriber: subscriber, upstream: upstream, getCache: getCache, setCache: setCache)
        subscriber.receive(subscription: subscription)
    }
    
    init(_ upstream: Upstream, getCache: @escaping ()->Output?, setCache: @escaping (Output)->Void) {
        self.upstream = upstream
        self.getCache = getCache
        self.setCache = setCache
    }
}
```

This is followed up with a `Subscription`:

```
extension CachePublisher {
    class CachePublisherSubscription<S: Subscriber>: Subscription where S.Input == Upstream.Output, S.Failure == Upstream.Failure {
        var subscriber: S
        var upstream: Upstream
        
        var setCache: (Output)->Void
        var getCache: ()->Output?
        
        init(subscriber: S, upstream: Upstream, getCache: @escaping ()->Output?, setCache: @escaping (Output)->Void) {
            self.subscriber = subscriber
            self.upstream = upstream
            self.getCache = getCache
            self.setCache = setCache
        }
        
        func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {
            ///check the cache for a value that satisfies the type
            ///return a value from the upstream publisher if not
            if let output = self.getCache() {
                subscriber.receive(output)
            } else {
                //forward an upstream value?
                //how? an entire publisher/subscriber chain?
            }
            
        }
        
        func cancel() {
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, a function so you can pass the upstream publisher to the `CachePublisher`

```
extension Publisher {
    func cache() -> CachePublisher<Self> {
        return CachePublisher(self, getCache: { nil }, setCache: { _ in })
    }
}
```

I have no idea what to put in the required methods, or how to pass the subscriber up the chain to the upstream publisher. Or how to capture values from the upstream publisher.

The idea that came into my head is that downstream subscribers sort of create a nesting doll type structure, but I just don't know how to connect them.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the whole `Publisher`/`Publishers`/`Subscription` dance, you can customize the `subscribe` method without needing a custom class. Existing Combine operators to the rescue here :).

```swift
extension Publisher {
    func cache(read: @escaping Publishers.Cache<Self>.Read,
               write: @escaping Publishers.Cache<Self>.Write) -> Publishers.Cache<Self> {
        Publishers.Cache(upstream: self, read: read, write: write)
    }
}

extension Publishers {
    struct Cache<P: Publisher>: Publisher {
        typealias Output = P.Output
        typealias Failure = P.Failure
        
        typealias Read = () -> Output?
        typealias Write = (Output) -> Void
        
        private let upstream: P
        private let read: Read
        private let write: Write
        
        init(upstream: P, read: @escaping Read, write: @escaping Write) {
            self.upstream = upstream
            self.read = read
            self.write = write
        }
        
        func receive<S>(subscriber: S) where S : Subscriber, Self.Failure == S.Failure, Self.Output == S.Input {
            if let cachedValue = read() {
                Just(cachedValue).setFailureType(to: Failure.self).receive(subscriber: subscriber)
            } else {
                upstream.handleEvents(receiveOutput: write).receive(subscriber: subscriber)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`handleEvents` kinda breaks the "pure functions" paradigm that is recommended to be followed when writing custom operators pipelines, however as you anyway need to write to the cache, and that's already a side effect, the added impact of calling `handleEvents` is not that big.

Comment: Gotcha. This is a good step that I'll use to do some exploring, but is there a way to do it in the "pure function" way? The reason I asked to do it that way is because I thought it would be helpful in learning to make other, pure-function-based solutions.

Comment: @promacuser well, I don't think you can have a clean pipeline if you also need to update the cache, as that would be a side effect, and would break the "purity" of the pipeline wherever you put it.

Comment: I did a bit more reading and I think what I am trying to do requires the Subscription to also be a Subscriber. I'm going to write another answer to see if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Making the custom `Subscription` also a `Subscriber` allows it to connect both directions. When the cache getter produces a result, it is sent to the downstream subscriber. However, when the getter does not, the demand is forwarded to the upstream publisher, which emits a value.

That value is then captured by the `Subscriber` methods of the custom `Subscription` and forwarded to the downstream subscriber.

```
extension CachePublisher {
    class CachePublisherSubscription<Downstream: Subscriber>: Subscription, Subscriber where Downstream.Input == Upstream.Output, Downstream.Failure == Upstream.Failure {
        typealias Input = Upstream.Output
        typealias Failure = Upstream.Failure
        
        var downstream: Downstream
        var upstream: Upstream
        var upstreamSubscription: Subscription?
        
        var read: Read
        var write: Write
                
        init(downstream: Downstream, upstream: Upstream, read: @escaping Read, write: @escaping Write) {
            self.downstream = downstream
            self.upstream = upstream
            self.read = read
            self.write = write
            
            upstream.subscribe(self)
        }
        
        func request(_ demand: Subscribers.Demand) {
            if let cachedValue = read() {
                downstream.receive(cachedValue)
            } else {
                upstreamSubscription?.request(demand)
            }
        }
        
        // keep a reference to the upstream subscription
        func receive(subscription: Subscription) {
            self.upstreamSubscription = subscription
        }
        // pass input downstream
        func receive(_ input: Input) -> Subscribers.Demand {
            self.write(input)
            return downstream.receive(input)
        }
        // pass completion downstream
        func receive(completion: Subscribers.Completion<Failure>) {
            downstream.receive(completion: completion)
        }
        
        func cancel() {
            //TO-DO: Finish cancellation
        }
    }
}
```